# A Possible Un-Fixable Provisioning Profile Error in Xcode? Anyone Else?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6, provisioning-profile

So I haven't opened my Xcode project in a while and haven't even looked at any code in months. Now after banging my head through the wall, still no App money in my pockets, and losing my mind over some stupid apple program errors I remember why...

The full error is:

*"App installation failed - A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found"*

Now I know this error has been posted here multiple times and each has a set of answers that miraculously has helped some people, some of which are the most insane answers that are for particular events such as one guy's device date was set in future...uhh

Anyway's, after 2 days of trying every single "Answer" for this error and over an hour on the phone and letting an unexperienced Apple supporter take over my screen and getting absolutely nowhere I need some serious professional help from who else but stack overflow geniuses, right? Also I'll mention Apple does its fair share of going to this forum when they are clueless. Ha! Who would of thought,oh ya, probably all of us.

Continuing on here... To me a lot of these answers are too complex when Its simple to me. Its saying my device doesn't have the provisioning profile, which checking in the Devices window and right clicking to show the device's provisioning profiles, there are none obviously. When of course there should be. Now there is a button to manually install the provisioning profile. **NOW, ONLY IF THIS WORKED!** it doesn't and that in itself is something also listed on here and for me directly responds to my error.. (Just Search: provisioning profiles won't install on device)

http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x/known-issues-with-ios#manual-installation-of-provisioning-profiles

This above link is a site that is the only thing that is agreeing something else is wrong here and would also explain what I already was sensing. This project ran fine last I ran it when my device was on iOS 7. Also another device thats on iOS 6 gets the provisioning profiles. So clearly iOS 8 is bugged like it always has been and I don't know what to do about it cause Apple makes horrible buggy updates to products and doesn't let you downgrade.

So please, does anyone have any idea how to get around this?

Bonus Question: Why are we always "getting around" super simple errors that never get fixed by Apple?